# p5 js input does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, input, processing, p5.js

I have a very simple p5 sketch that is running in my desktop computer pretty well. But when I hosted that with github pages just to see if it works on mobile devices I found it not working properly. I had just a single input box created in my sketch.

This is the `sketch.js` :

```
var inputBox;
function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    inputBox = createInput();
    inputBox.size(200,50);
}
```

This is the index.html :-

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the link for my github page :

> https://irtiaz-kabir.github.io/Test/

When I run this in my mobile or tab and tap on the input field it never focuses.

Please solve my problem.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, without all that extra code included?

Comment: Are you talking about the index.html? That is a regular index.html for p5 js. I just linked p5.js, p5.dom.js, p5.sound.js script files. And I think, the sketch.js is very simple!